# Import array stored in angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm super new to Angular and JS in general. Basically I have an array thats stored in a var inside a factory and I want that entire array (this.insights) to get imported(?) into my directive.

I believe I need to do something like scope.insights = [];

```
var Piece = function (parameters) {
  this.thing = null;
  this.that = null;
  this.insights = [
    {
      id: 1,
    }
    {
      id: 2,
    }
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject this factory in directive same way you inject other services.

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function(Piece) {
  return {
   restrict: 'AE',
   replace: 'true',
   template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>',
   controller: function(){
     var kek = Piece.insights;
   }
  };
});
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply, this was exactly what i needed